# Flickr background download session failed: You do not have permission to access the requested resource

Tags: ios, xcode5, flickr

I have a school assignment where I need to use this project: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Photomania_2.zip

When I first downloaded it, it worked fine. I was working on it one day, when I got this message: "Flickr background download session failed: You do not have permission to access the requested resource."

I didn't know how to fix it, so I went back and downloaded it again to see if I did something to the code that caused that I got that error. When I downloaded a fresh copy of the photomania application, I would yet again get that error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Show some code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did it stop working on June 27th? [The Flickr API went SSL-only on that day](http://code.flickr.net/2014/04/30/flickr-api-going-ssl-only-on-june-27th-2014/). That project probably needs its API endpoints updating to use SSL. I'd ask your tutor about that. Or just try updating all the API endpoints you can find to use the appropriate https: equivalents, as described in that blog post.

Comment: Yes it did actually. I'll check it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. Matt hit the nail on the head. Make sure you add in your API key and do a find/replace to make all "http:" references "https:".